# Subsequence that converges to $\lim \text{inf}$

Tags: real-analysis

> If $X=(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ show that there is
>   a subsequence of $X$ which converges to $\lim \text{inf} (x_n)$.

My attempt:

Let $\lim \text{inf} (x_n) =x$. Then by definition, there are infintely many $x_n$ such that $$x-\epsilon <x_n<x+\epsilon.$$ Which implies that $\exists$  $x_{n_k}$ such that
$x_{n_k}\in \{a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon\}= a-\epsilon <x_n<a+\epsilon$...
But now how can I get my subsequence to converge to $\lim \text{inf} (x_n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $\varepsilon_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and use your method to extract a single $x_n$ for each $\varepsilon_n$.  Because there are infinitely many $x_n$ to choose from for each $\varepsilon_n$, we can make it so that we choose in order so that it actually is a subsequence.

Comment: Why exactly did you choose $\varepsilon_n = \frac{1}{n}?$?

Comment: Because it goes to $0$ and it's enumerated by an integer.  I could have picked $\varepsilon_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ if I wanted.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. I am going to try and attempt your technique.

Comment: If I choose $\varepsilon_n = \frac{1}{n}$ then $|x_n-x|<\epsilon_n \implies |x_{n_k}-x|< \varepsilon_n =\frac{1}{n}$. Is this correct?

Comment: If you're choosing $x_{n_k}$ to be such that $|x_{n_k} - x| < \varepsilon_k$ and that $n_k < n_{k+1}$, then yes, that is fine.

Comment: Last question, why does $n_k < n_{k+1}$?

Comment: We can pick this so that we actually have a proper subsequence.  You don't want to be picking a sequence which isn't ordered properly.  Because for each choice of $\varepsilon_k$ there are infinitely many choices for $x_{n_k}$, we might as well pick $x_{n_k}$ satisfying $n_k > n_{k-1}$.

Comment: But if we defined $\epsilon =\frac{1}{n}$ then wouldn't $n_{k}>n_{k+1}$ instead of $n_k < n_{k+1}$?

Comment: No, typically $x_{n_k} > x_{n_{k+1}}$ but not $n_k > n_{k+1}$

Comment: Hmm, confusing, maybe I should read up more on subsequence. Thanks a lot, muzz!